# Удалить строки совпадающие со строками с другого файла

Tags: python-3.x, shell, sed

Есть файл test1.txt и файл test2.txt, оба состоят из строк со случайными символами. Но некоторые строки совпадают и в файле test1.txt и в файле test2.txt

Пример:

```
$ cat test1.txt 
случайные_символы1
случайные_символы2
случайные_символы3
случайные_символы4
!@#%^%&^*^
8246****

$ cat test2.txt 
случайные_символы1
!@#%^%&^*^
8246****
случайные_символы20
```

Хочу получить файл test1.txt с результатом:

```
случайные_символы2
случайные_символы3
случайные_символы4
```

Нашел решение вида:

```
sed -i -f <(sed 's,^,/^,;s,$,/d,' test2.txt) test1.txt
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
sed: file /dev/fd/63 line 3: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Я так понял ругается на строку 8246****

Как сделать так, чтоб можно было обрабатывать любую строку, не зависимо, какие символы находятся в ней? Либо может есть другое решение задачи?

---

Решение:
с файлами меньше 1GB, отлично подошли ответы от 'Эникейщик'

Т.к у меня файлы намного больше - подошло вот это:

```
comm -2 -3 test1.txt test2.txt
```

Comment: Метка python просто так?

Comment: Нет, просто решение на питоне тоже подходит, если такое есть

Comment: Порядок строк важен?

Comment: Нет, порядок строк не важен. Я потом отсортирую в случае чего.

Comment: можно еще `grep` к примеру использовать, если строки полностью в файлах идентичные

Comment: программа [*comm*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178576+comm) — ваш друг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно считать оба файла в списки (через readlines(), например), из списков сделать множества и вычесть второе из первого:

```
file1 = ["случайные_символы1","случайные_символы2","случайные_символы3","случайные_символы4","!@#%^%&^*^","8246****"]

file2 = ["случайные_символы1","!@#%^%&^*^","8246****","случайные_символы20"]

s1 = set(file1)
s2 = set(file2)
print (s1-s2)
```

---

Вариант для очень больших файлов:

```
with open("text2.txt") as file2:
    data2 = f1.readlines()
    s2 = set(data1)
s1 = []
with open("text1.txt") as file1:
    for line in file2:
        if line not in s2:
            s1.append(line)
print(s1)
```

Считываем второй файл целиком, а первый потом читаем построчно и проверяем на наличие строчки во втором файле.

Comment: не хватило 16GB оперативки, под рабочие файлы :(
но с маленькими файлами работает

Comment: возможно есть способ, чтоб использовалось место на диске, вместо оперативки?

Comment: Можно считать в память только один файл, а второй читать построчно и проверять. Завтра набросаю код.

Comment: Было бы замечательно.

Comment: Добавил вариант.

Comment: Всеравно упирается в оперативку 16GB. Хотя файл "text2.txt" весит всего 718MB

Comment: А другой файл сколько?